# как работают !! и ! в js(проверка на пустоту массива)

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
    if(!task || task == null || task.length<=0)
    {
        //res.status(404).send("The task not found");
        res.status(404);
        return res.send(`The task  id=${idTask} not found`);
    }
```

В коде вместо task.length<=0 пробовал !(task.length) но условия не исполняться а !!task.length работает, хотя должно быть наоборот.

Пример

```js
const idTask = 2;
const tasks = [{"id":0,"title":"Пограти в теніc"},{"id":1,"title":"Зробити завдання"},{"id":2,"title":"Поh"},{"id":3,"title":"Зробити завдання 1"},{"id":4,"title":"Поh"},{"id":5,"title":"Зробити завдання 3"},{"id":6,"title":"Зробити завдання 4"}]
const task = tasks.find(t=>t.id == idTask);

  if(!task || task == null || task.length<=0)
    {
      console.log("Исполнено");
    }
  else
  {
      console.log("НЕ исполнено");
  }

 if(!task || task == null || !task.length)
    {
      console.log("Исполнено");
    }
  else
  {
      console.log("НЕ исполнено");
  }
```

Два ифа возвращают  разные результаты. Почему???)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var task = [];
console.log(!task);
console.log(task == null);
console.log(task.length<=0);
console.log(!task.length);
console.log(!!task.length);
```

---

> Два ифа возвращают разные результаты. Почему?

Потому что пременная `task` не массив, и у нее нет свойства `length`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

```js
var a;
console.log(a);
console.log(a <= 0);
console.log(!a);
```

Проверки `if (task)` или `if (!task)` вполне достаточно.

Comment: ну так  !(task.length)  должно было подходить к условию, а условия не срабатывало а task.length<=0 работает.

Comment: @BogdanZhila Совершенно верно. Создайте работающий пример, в котором они разные.

Comment: Добавил код в начало (Вопрос). Возвращает разные результаты. @Igor

Comment: @BogdanZhila Потому что пременная `task` не массив, и у нее нет свойства `length`.

Comment: а что это, и как правильно проверить? @Igor

Comment: @BogdanZhila Проверки `if (task)` или `if (!task)` вполне достаточно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113344/discussion-between-bogdan-zhila-and-igor).

Answer (score 1):

Вам для начала надо понимать что, возвращает число в `javascript`, как булиан. Например, `null, undefinde, 0, ''` возвращает `false`. Кстати, длинна пустово массива тоже будет `false`, потому-что, `anyArray.length === 0`, а 0, как мы знаем возвращает `false`. А теперь можно поговорить об `!` и `!!`. Так вот, `!` если сказать простым языком, инвертирует в противоположное `(значение булиан)`. Т.е. `true` превращает в `false`, а `false` в `true`. Знак `!!` именно что, ковертирует другие типы данных в булиан.

Answer (score 1):

Я лишь добавлю легко проверяемой информации к заданному вопросу.
JavaScipt в нем есть много удивительных вещей, я лишь приведу чуток сравнения

```js
console.log('------------- true -------------------');

var a = true;
console.log('a === a => ', a === a); // true
console.log('!!a == a => ', !!a == a); // true
console.log('a < 0 => ', a < 0); // false
console.log('a > 0 => ', a > 0); // true
console.log('a == 0 => ', a == 0); // false
console.log('a <= 0 =>', a <= 0); // false
console.log('a >= 0 =>', a >= 0); // true
//тут всё нормально вопросов нет 


console.log('--------------- undefined -----------------');
var a = undefined;
console.log('a === a => ', a === a); // true
console.log('!!a == a => ', !!a == a); // false
console.log('a < 0 => ', a < 0); // false
console.log('a > 0 => ', a > 0); // false
console.log('a == 0 => ', a == 0); // false
console.log('a <= 0 =>', a <= 0); // false
console.log('a >= 0 =>', a >= 0); // false
//ну ладно ок

console.log('---------------- null ----------------');
var a = null;
console.log('a === a =>', a === a); // true, тут интересненко null === null
console.log('!!a == a => ', !!a == a); // false
console.log('a < 0 => ', a < 0); // false
console.log('a > 0 => ', a > 0); // false
console.log('a == 0 => ', a == 0); // false
console.log('a <= 0 =>', a <= 0); // о чудо true
console.log('a >= 0 =>', a >= 0); // о чудо true


console.log('-------------- [] ------------------');

var a = [];
console.log('a === a =>', a === a); // true
console.log('!!a == a => ', !!a == a); // false
console.log('a < 0 => ', a < 0); // false
console.log('a > 0 => ', a > 0); // false
console.log('a == 0 => ', a == 0); // true, ладно пусть [] == 0
console.log('a <= 0 =>', a <= 0); // true
console.log('a >= 0 =>', a >= 0); // true    

console.log('-------------- {} ------------------');
var a = {};
console.log('!!a == a => ', !!a == a); // false
console.log('a < 0 => ', a < 0); // false
console.log('a > 0 => ', a > 0); // false
console.log('a == 0 => ', a == 0); // false, а тут почему нет
console.log('a <= 0 =>', a <= 0); // false
console.log('a >= 0 =>', a >= 0); // false

console.log('------------- NaN -------------------');
var a = NaN;
console.log('a === a =>', a === a); // false, все убили null === null true, а NaN === NaN false
console.log('!!a == a => ', !!a == a); // false
console.log('a < 0 => ', a < 0); // false
console.log('a > 0 => ', a > 0); // false
console.log('a == 0 => ', a == 0); // false
console.log('a <= 0 =>', a <= 0); // false
console.log('a >= 0 =>', a >= 0); // false
```

смотря на данное понимаешь что в JS при сравнении нужно знать что там может лежать в переменной и быть предельно внимательным. Поскольку данное поведение не свойственно всем языкам. Всё это исходит из тех спецификации.